# Syncing External Azure AD users in B2B collaboration

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I have several external AD guest users in my Azure AD organization.  One of those users changed his `User Principal Name` in the external AD but the change is not reflected in my Azure AD.

But I cannot change his User Principal Name in my organization using the Azure portal (it's greyed out when I click 'Edit').  I also noticed that in the "All Users" table which shows all users in my organization, the "Directory synced" column has "No".

**Question**: how do I turn on syncing so that for user that has `Source="External Azure Active Directory"` when the user principal name or email or other information changes, the Azure AD properties in my organization is automatically updated?

Answer (score 2):

You can send out invites again to fix this issue.

To change the UPN, User name and MailNickname:

1. Connect-AzureAD
2. Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId  | fl
3. Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId  -UserPrincipalName bbb.aaa_xyz.com#EXT#@b2b.com
4. Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId  -MailNickName bbb.aaa_xyz.com#EXT#

Comment: Thanks, I was able to update UserPrincipalName and MailNickName manually.  So there is no automated syncing?

Comment: Also, I cannot update the **Mail** attribute (PrimarySmtpAddress), it didn't update.  How do I do this?  I tried using the ExchangeOnlineManagement module to execute Set-MailUser -Identity someone_example.com#EXT# -PrimarySmtpAddress someone@example.com but I receive a license error: "Organization
"xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" is not licensed for Exchange email functionality. Cmdlet usage is restricted."